# How to control the order in which JPA entities are created on Spring Boot App initialization?

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

How to control the order in which JPA entities are created on Spring Boot App initialization, when we use H2 or MySQL sometimes we feel the child table is created prior to the parent table. In such a scenario schema creation fails causing application to not startup

Comment: What do you by "entity creation"? Instantiation is controlled by your code. Class loading is done by the JVM, Schema generation is done by the JPA implementation and apart from bugs should not cause problems.

Comment: I meant for Table creation only

Comment: check all your entity annotations (@ Entity, @ Table (also name etc) and the relationsship annotations (like @ ManyToOne etc.) in your entity classes

Comment: Don't use hibernate auto-cration strategy (dll-auto, drop-create etc..). Best practice is migration control frameworks like liquibase/flyway etc. It gives you total control.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about a liquibase like framework, In that case you will need to manually order if for example A has a foreign key referring from table B, then table A needs to be created before B. Unless this there is no issue coming from JPA or Spring Boot because entity classes get linked with annotation correctly so when they are called necessary proxy classes get created and linked accordingly.